# Making a 2D block matrix of variables in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I would like to make a 2D matrix for the model:

`y = Mx`

where M is a block matrix with the form:

[image]

and A and B are square matrices that contain a mixture of variables and constants.
[image]
[image]

How can I set up the matrix, M, in Tensorflow that will keep the block structure and only optimize for specific elements of A and B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a11 = tf.Variable(1.0)
a12 = tf.Variable(2.0)
a22 = tf.Variable(3.0)
b12 = tf.Variable(4.0)
zero = tf.constant(0.0)

A = tf.reshape(tf.stack([a11,a12,zero,a22]),(2,2))
B = tf.reshape(tf.stack([zero,b12,zero,zero]),(2,2))
M = tf.concat([tf.concat([A,B],1),tf.concat([B,A],1)],0)
```

Comment: This is what I need, thanks! Just curious, if I wanted to scale up my code (A and B are actually 6x6 matrices), is there a way to use loops?

Comment: For the more general problem, of defining a large matrix `A` such that some of its elements are constants (non trainable), I think I have a nice solution but it's hard fit in here. The idea is to define (1) a list of indices where the matrix should be constant, and (2) a list of `tf.Variable`s; and then use a loop or list comprehension to build the final matrix.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!